# Брать значения ключей из другого массива

Tags: php, массивы

Как получить значение из второго массива
первый основной массив

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'count' => '1',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'count' => '1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '3',
    'count' => '1',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => '3',
    'count' => '1',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => '3',
    'count' => '1',
  ),
    и тд......
)
```

второй с описанием id

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'name' => 'Oleg',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'name' => 'Irina',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => '3',
    'name' => 'Dmitriy',
  ),
    и тд......
)
```

Нужно получить вот такой массив добавив значения из второго массива сравнивая id

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'count' => '1',
    'name' => 'Oleg',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'count' => '1',
    'name' => 'Irina',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '3',
    'count' => '1',
    'name' => 'Dmitriy',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => '3',
    'count' => '1',
    'name' => 'Dmitriy',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => '3',
    'count' => '1',
    'name' => 'Dmitriy',
  ),
    и тд......
)
```

Answer (score 1):

разложите второй массив на пары ключ-значение с помощью

```
$names = array_column($second, 'name', 'id');
```

пройдитесь по первому и добавьте имена

```
array_walk($first, function(&$v) use ($names){ 
               $v['name'] = $names[$v['id']]; 
            }) ;
```

Comment: аргументы у array_column в обратном порядке

Comment: @splash58 да,поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде получилось, а как сделать если больше значений

```
  array (
    'id' => '23',
    'name' => '',
    'add_name' => '',
    'icon' => '',
    'grade' => '',
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавил таким образом) всем спасибо за идеальное решение!

```
$name = array_column($slot_info, 'name', 'id',);
$icon0 = array_column($slot_info, 'icon0', 'id',);
$add_name = array_column($slot_info, 'add_name', 'id',);

array_walk($inv_slot_array_id_all, function(&$v) use ($name){ 
       $v['name'] = $name[$v['id']]; 
    }) ;
array_walk($inv_slot_array_id_all, function(&$v) use ($icon0){ 
       $v['icon0'] = $icon0[$v['id']]; 
    }) ;  
array_walk($inv_slot_array_id_all, function(&$v) use ($add_name){ 
       $v['add_name'] = $add_name[$v['id']]; 
    }) ;
```